# Change 2 Divs Content via Ajax/XML

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, html

I'm making an employee directory page for a website. The page will have about 2 dozen thumbnail photos of employees, and when clicked, 2 divs below the thumbs will change to show a larger photo, and the bio of the employee. I was told to look into using AJAX for this, since I don't want the page to refresh/change from one employee to another. The site is being built in .net using C#, and as of now, we haven't used JQuery or Mootools on this site, so we'd be open to using either one.

So here's a snippet of my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<employees>
    <employee_01>
        <name>Employee J. Name</name>
        <title>Big Cheese</title>
        <email>email@email.com</email>
        <phone>(555) 333-4444</phone>
        <bio><p>This is paragraph one of the bio. This could be several sentences long.</p>

<p>This is paragraph 2 for this bio. It may or may not be as long as the first one.</p></bio>
        <photo_url>employee_photo01.jpg</photo_url>
    </employee_01>
    <employee_02>
        <name></name>
        <title></title>
        <email></email>
        <phone></phone>
        <bio></bio>
        <photo_url></photo_url>
    </employee_02>
</employees>
```

Here is the Div structure that needs to be replaced with the xml data.

```
 <div id="employee_bio_container">
    <div id="employee_photo"><img src="images/employee_photo01.jpg" alt="Employee Name" /></div>
    <div id="employee_bio">
        <h1>Name</h1>
        <h5>title</h5>
        <h5><a href="mailto:email">email</a><br />
        phone goes here</h5>
        <hr />
<p>This is the bio that will be replaced</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

So I need to change the src for the image in the "employee_photo" div, along with the alt text for it, and display the name, title, email address, phone, and bio in the "employee_bio" div, along with changing the URL of the mailto link.

I've never touched AJAX before, and I'm having a hard time making sense of the tutorials I've found so far. Any tips or directions to point me?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd start with, fix your XML.  `<employee_02>`?  <cringe>

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, follow the example in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
```

1. In your ajax success, process data object. Your data object should contain the employee info and image src
2. manipulate your html in javascript, set the img.src to the url, and then build the content of your employee_bio element